# Can you push to a viewController and be a part of that controllers navigation?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

Lets say I have the following `storyboard` structure

`navigation controller` -> `class A` -> `class B`

And seperate from the `navigation controller` I have `class C`.

Now I would like to navigate from `class C´ to` class B`and end up inside the`navigation controller`of which`class B`belongs. So if I press back, I end up in`class A`.

I tried by creating a seperate class, subclassed from `UINavigationController`

```
class MyNavigation: UINavigationController {}
```

Then in the `storyboard` I set the `navigationController` to this class.

In `class C` I tried the following code:

```
let navigation = UINavigationController() as? Myavigation

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)

guard let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyId") as? FirmwareViewController else { return }
           
navigation?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

But this did nothing. And yes, it passed the guard. So is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You say " I would like to navigate from class C´ to class B and end up inside the navigation controller of which class B belongs." It isn't clear what you mean. A navigation controller manages a "stack" of child view controllers. If you want to display a `class C` view controller on the stack, just push it onto the stack like you are doing with any other view controller. There are methods that will pop back to any view controller on the stack, include the root view controller. (See `popToRootViewController(animated:)` and `popToViewController(_:animated:)`. Just use one of those.

Comment: And this code: `let navigation = UINavigationController() as? Myavigation` is fatally flawed. The construct `UINavigationController()` creates a brand new navigation controller that is not part of your view hierarchy and will be deallocated as soon as you exit your function. Plus, the `as? Myavigation` cast will fail, causing  the whole expression to return nil.

Comment: @DuncanC Ah, ok, so I can't actually jump into a navigation controller from the outside, if that makes sense? The reason I'm asking is that class c isn't and can't be a part of the navigation controller, but I still need to go from C to B. But I guess that has to be done without being inside the navigation controller.

Comment: What do you mean "isn't part of the navigation controller"? Do you mean that you don't want view controller C to be in the navigation stack?

Comment: Exactly, class C can't be a part of the stack.

Comment: So how do you expect to switch between class c and the navigation stack? Display C modally on top of the stack? Swap out the root view controller of the window? What will the user experience be?

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt - *"class C can't be a part of the stack"* ... why not? Do you simply want `C` to show *without* the navigation bar at the top (with your own designed "back" button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use following -

```
let cNavCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: c)
cNavCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
b.navigationController?.present(cNavCtrl, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Then from inside `c`, you can add a `backButton/cross` that'd call following -

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This way - your `c` is never a part of `b.navigationController` and tapping the back from `c` takes you back to `b`.

Comment: A navigation controller inside a navigation controller? That's going to create nested navigation bars, which will be a confusing UX.

Comment: It's a presentation, not a push.

Comment: So it is. My mistake.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Many thanks.